# foreign complexType from imported schema raises error in xml instance

Tags: xml, xsd

I get this error

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Value'. One of '{"http://www.example.org/fooBar":Value}' is 
>    expected.

The xml instance I'm using is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Foo xmlns="http://www.example.org/Foo">
    <Element>some Data</Element>
    <Element>some Data</Element>
    <Element>some Data</Element>
    <Bar xmlns="http://www.example.org/Bar">
        <Item>
            <Value>My Value</Value>
        </Item>
    </Bar>
    <Element>some Data</Element>
    <Element>some Data</Element>
    <Element>some Data</Element>
</Foo>
```

This is the `Bar` schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fooBar='http://www.example.org/fooBar' targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/Bar"
    xmlns:Bar="http://www.example.org/Bar" elementFormDefault='qualified'>
    <import namespace='http://www.example.org/fooBar' />
    <element name="Bar">
        <complexType>
            <sequence>
                <element name="Item" type="fooBar:itemType" />
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </element>
</schema>
```

And this is the imported `fooBar` schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/fooBar" xmlns:fooBar="http://www.example.org/fooBar"
    elementFormDefault='qualified'>
    <complexType name="itemType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="Value" type="string" />
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
</schema>
```

I suppose it is not getting the namespace right? But why?
If I drag the `itemType` from the `fooBar` schema to the `Bar` schema (`Value` stays in fooBar) the error is the same but this time it complains about the `Value` element.
Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? It seems it can't handle types from imported schemes.

EDIT:

To clarify what I want to do maybe this example helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Foo xmlns="http://www.example.org/Foo">
    <Element>some Data</Element>
    <Element>some Data</Element>
    <Element>some Data</Element>
    <Bar xmlns="http://www.example.org/Bar" xmlns:mon="http://www.example.org/fooBar">
        <Item>
            <mon:Value>My Value</mon:Value>
        </Item>
    </Bar>
    <Element>some Data</Element>
    <Element>some Data</Element>
    <Element>some Data</Element>
</Foo>
```

I want to save the user (writing the xml) from needing to know what namespaces `Value` is in. He should just drop in `Bar` and be able to go below there like "nothing happend".
It seems this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that what I want to do is impossible. You have to do it like I showed in the last example.
Thanks go to the #xml channel on freenode!

Answer (score 0):

Your Bar element is in namespace "http://www.example.org/Bar" but your schema requires it to be in namespace "http://www.example.org/fooBar"

Comment: Thanks can you elaborate? Which line requires `Bar` to be in the namespace `fooBar`? I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

With the schema documents and the XML instance as you have shown them, the error is that the Value element should be in namespace "http://www.example.org/fooBar" when it is actually in namespace "http://www.example.org/Bar". This doesn't correlate with the error message; from your decription I suspect the error message was from a different attempt.

The reason Value should be in "http://www.example.org/fooBar" is that this is the targetNamespace of the schema document in which Value is declared, and the schema document uses elementFormDefault="qualified" which indicates that the targetNamespace applies to both global and local element declarations.

Comment: Ah you are right I mixed up the names. The error is actually about `Value` not `Item`. I get almost the same error for `Item` when I take the `qualified` out of the `Bar` schema. If I take out the `qualified` from the `fooBar` schema the error changes just to `cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Value'. One of '{Value}' is 
 expected.` Which is even more strange because it is Value and it worked the same way in the `Bar` schema with `Item` as I'm doing the same thing here. This is why I suspected the way I'm importing is not how it should be done.

Comment: The message "Invalid content was found starting with element 'Value'. One of '{Value}' is expected" is a an inelegant way of telling you that the local name is OK, but the namespace is wrong.